# Laravel API Session data returns different values from different clients

Tags: php, laravel, api, session, session-variables

I am setting and attempting to retrieve a session value from a Laravel application, using Laravel API. To enable me set and retrieve session data with the API, I have added the classes `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class` and `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to the `app\Kernel.php` file. When I try to set and get the session data using the HTTP client Postman is works fine. However if I try to retrieve the same session data using another HTTP client Insomnia or even using Laravel Tinker, it returns null. This is the controller which contains the methods that sets and gets the session data:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getSession(Request $request) {

        $value = $request->session()->get('info');
        return response()
            ->json([
                'done' => $value
            ]);

    }

    public function setSession(Request $request) {

        $value = $request->session()->put('info', 'hello from larasession');
        return response()
            ->json([
                'done' => 'session set'
            ]);
    }
}
```

How do I solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how you can use tinker to get session as it has its own command line context.Regarding Insomnia, I have used that might be due to bug/improper content type

Comment: You can use tinker to get session data. E.g session('info')